# Apt insistently want to remove wine32(and libwine) when I just give it the command "apt install ffmpeg". Why?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

When I just give the command "apt install ffmpeg", Apt insistently want to remove wine32, libwine, libopenal1:i386 libsndio7.0 libsndio7.0:i386. Why?

Comment: Why are you installing that package? It's installed by default. Are you using a ppa?

Comment: Don't *describe* the output. *Show us* the actual input and output.

Comment: The problem is that I wanted to do this and ran the apt command redirecting the output to a file. Apt decided not to ask for confirmation and installed ffmpeg by removing wine32 for me, as promised earlier. Therefore, believe me the old admin word for word.